# Javascript OnClick Event - 2 functions

Tags: javascript, popup, onclick

i used a onclick event for this js function:

```
window.opener.location.href =foobar;
```

After loading foobar in the Parent window this window should close. 
It is a popup (opended with JS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.close()
```

should work.

Comment: It will if you put window.close() AFTER the location change.

Comment: like so: `window.opener.location.href =foobar;window.close();`

Comment: Ok i tried again and it works. I tried this yesterday and i did not. But ok... i dont know why. Thanks volks